# Creating table of point in polygon results using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, spatial-join

I have one PostGIS table of polygons like this:

```
index | lat | lon | geom
```

where geom is a polygon d-type 
ex. POLYGON ((x1,y1,x2,y2.....))

```
CREATE TABLE buildings2 (
    index integer PRIMARY KEY,
    lat numeric,
    lon numeric,
    geometry geometry(Polygon,4326),
    poly geometry(Polygon,4326)
);

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX buildings2_pkey ON buildings2(index int4_ops);
```

And another of points like this:

```
index | point_id | lat | lon | geom
```

ex. geom = SRID=4326;POINT(32.123 12.123), lat = 12.123, lon = 32.123

```
CREATE TABLE pings (
    index SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    ad_id text,
    lat numeric,
    lon numeric,
    time text,
    hour integer,
    geom geometry(Point,4326)
);

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX pings_pkey ON pings(index int4_ops);
```

I want to create a new table that has all the points that are in polygons of the polygon table. My points file is large (100M rows), buildings(170), so:

What query am I supposed to use to create this table? I have tried contains, intersect, and within, but I am not sure which is the best for my problem, and all the stack exchange answers I have looked at provide a different solution.

Comment: Now we're getting close. Row counts? Spatial index(es)? Which of the two geometry columns in buildings2 is being queried? The actual query you issued? BTW: the `text` "time" field probably ought to be a `timestamp`  type to take advantage of temporal functions.

Comment: @Vince Added row counts, I don't thing I have spatial indexes or know how to add those. My question literally is what query should I be using. I understand that for 'time', for the purposes of this join it is not needed.